# How would I convert an SVG in a web page that a user draws on to a PNG or JPG?

Tags: php, javascript, html, canvas, svg

I have a web page that has an iframe with an SVG which allows the user to draw on it. When they're done, I want to convert their drawing to an image. How would I do this?

(It needs to work in iOS Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Safari desktop, IE9+)

I'd prefer a client-side solution but could PHP solutions are ok.

Comment: HTML5 `<canvas>` allows you to save out as a png with javascript (client side).

Comment: So, would I read the path data of the SVG and write to canvas object?

Comment: Haven't used it but this says it does what you want: https://code.google.com/p/canvg/

Comment: Allows for SVG -> Canvas -> png transition all on the client side

Answer (score 2):

I recently did this for a project I'm working on.
There is different approaches, but this is what I went with.

Using **jQuery** and **canvg** (http://code.google.com/p/canvg/)

--

My JavaScript function

```
function getChartData(chartDiv) {

    var svg = $('#' + chartDiv).find('svg').parent().html();
    $('<canvas id="newCanvas_' + chartDiv + '" width="' + $('#' + chartDiv).width() + 'px" height="' + $('#' + chartDiv).height() + 'px" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 0;"></canvas>').insertAfter('body');
    canvg(document.getElementById('newCanvas_' + chartDiv), svg);

    var imgData = document.getElementById('newCanvas_' + chartDiv).toDataURL("image/png");
    return imgData;
}
```

Then I had my `svg` element within a DIV.

```
<div id="mydrawing">
    <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Then I ran the function to get the base64 encoded string of the SVG as an image.

```
base64string = getChartData('mydrawing');
```

Then I could use that variable to display the image in my HTML, or pass it to my PHP to generate an image to save.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, base64string" />
```

Comment: Thanks. This is great except it uses FlashCanvas on IE and I was hoping to stay away from Flash plugins.

Answer (score 0):

A server side solution would be:

1. Install `imagemagick.so` module on server

   parse the SVG as string and submit it to server (POST recommended)

   Insert additional XML tags (if required)

   Use PHP::imagemagick to convert it to a PNG or JPG.

   Return image to client, include the `header` declaration.

Note: Server side coding is more reliable, however the down side is graphical processing is heavy on CPU cycles (ie: lots of users may lag your server).